# IIS w3wp.exe just sits there and requests time out

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis-8

I am trying to run this website I have been working on at work locally at home, but I can't get it to work. I have tried recycling the dedicated app pool, restarting the site, killing the w3wp.exe processes, recompiling the site, deleting temporary ASP.net files from "C:\Windows...".

Making a new request from the browser brings up the worker process, which just sits there after a few seconds of low cpu usage. Then its memory usage continues to fluctuate by a few kilobytes though.

When I introduce a compilation error, the YSOD appears swiftly. Eliminating the compilation error takes me back to square one - the requests keep waiting and ultimately times out.

I am clueless as to what's going on. This is not the first time I've had this problem and before calling quits on microsoft stack, courtesy such frustrations, I am shouting out here - yep, am really stressed about this! Any Ideas guys? Or pointers on how to determine what's going on/debug? Framework version is 4.0, integrated mode.

Thanks

Comment: There are a host of troubleshooting tools, logging tools, and what not you can use to track down virtually any problem.  Just because you don't know what they are doesn't mean the "Microsoft stack" sucks or something, and you have to call it quits...  For instance, try using Tracing output and write trace statements to see where things are..  Or use the free trial of a tool like NewRelic to trace requests.

Comment: Also try looking for infinite loops that can end up making the server just spin. Also, look for cases where you may end up with infinite recursion as in the case of a property's getter returning not a local variable, but a reference to the property itself, which means the property keeps trying to return the property, keeps trying to return the property etc until a stack overflow error occurs.